# How to correctly compare two values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA procedure which is supposed to compare the values of two cells. In my case they are scalars, ranging from `1` to `3`. Basically, they are answers to questions. If they match, then I want to color a certain cell `green`, otherwise I want to make it `red`. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
Sub CheckBold()
'
' CheckBold Macro
'

'
 Row = ActiveCell.Row
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)).Font.Bold Then
 ActiveCell.Value = 1
 End If
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)).Font.Bold Then
 ActiveCell.Value = 2
 End If
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)).Font.Bold Then
 ActiveCell.Value = 3
 End If

  ActiveCell.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)).Value & ActiveCell.Value

If CInt(ActiveCell.Value) = CInt(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)).Value) Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 0)
Else
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 0, 0)
End If



End Sub
```

What happens is that always the code goes on the `Then` branch of the if, even though the values are different. Why do I get this behavior?

Comment: Try putting in `Worksheets("Sheet Name")` , instead of using `Sheets(1)`.

Comment: For checking if the code is using the correct sheet  or not, you can put `Debug.print ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name `  , which will print the name of the sheet you are referencing. I think the problem is in that only.

Comment: I used `Worksheets("SheetName")`, however I get the same behavior. If `ActiveCell.Value` is unassigned, that is when none of the checked cells are bold, it enters the `Then` branch. Otherwise, no matter the value it enters the `Else` branch. Why this behavior?

Comment: you don't need vba do do that, you should use Conditional formating

Comment: No need to convert your `Row` (presuming its of `Long` type) to `String`. Try something like this: `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D" & iRow).Font.Bold = True Then` where `iRow` is `Long` and `iRow = ActiveCell.Row`

Comment: Then, as @Mikku eludes to, try `Debug.Print` to check a) your row numbers, and b) if the cells are returning true as bold. I usually create a `Sub Test()` to do this individually when debugging.